# sum rows if another column has the word 'yes' in it using google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

:)
I'm trying to learn google sheets and there is something that I want to do and I can't figure out how.

```
A   B
5   yes
3   no
    yes
2   yes
    yes
5   no
    no
3   no
    yes
    yes
3   yes
    no
    no
5   no

=SUM(A1:A14)
```

as you can see in this example i have two columns

`A` - a number
`B` - yes or no

at the bottom I added `=SUM(A1:A14)` and it sums column A properly.

what If i want to sum column A only on rows that has `yes` in column B?

how can I do that ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUMIF(B:B,"yes",A:A)`

And if you expand into more columns, than `=SUMIFS()` will allow multiple conditions.

[Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)

Comment: i did =SUMIF(A:A,B:B,"yes")  and I get 
Argument must be a range.

Comment: this is the right syntax,thanks. =SUMIF(B:B,"yes",A:A)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the inputs slightly. It's an unfortunate thing with sumif and sumifs that they have different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:B; "select A where B='yes'"; 0))
```

or:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A; B:B="yes"))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(B:B="yes"; A:A; )))
```

Comment: nice thanks for showing me all the different ways to solve this problem